# External Database Scoped Credential via SAS

Tags: azure-synapse

Is it possible to create a data base scoped credential in synapse for Azure Blob Storage in SYnapse?
Tried this scenario :
`WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE', SECRET = '<your SAS secret without the preleading ?>'; CLOSE MASTER KEY;` -- only necessary if you need to close the master key context. (it will close with the session/query close)

But it is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SAS Database scoped credential for Azure Storage account is supported only in Azure SQL database and not in Synapse.
You need to use Storage account keys only in synapse.

In synapse you would get the below error:
Secret provided can not contain more than 120 characters. Please provide a valid credential.